# Ripple emulator with BlackBerry webworks 2.0 sdk blocking all ajax calls

Tags: ajax, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I am using the chrome extension: Ripple emulator on ubuntu 14.04 OS.
All ajax calls made from my BlackBerry webworks app, receive a state response of 0. Google Chrome code inspector says the status is (cancelled) and if you try to view the response it says: response data could not be loaded.

I have tried to start chrome with --disable-web-security

I have also added this to my config.xml

```
access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>
```

Starting with a <

I am able to make the same requests through postmaster (another google chrome plugin). So my issue is definitely Ripple based. All the answers I've found online seem to be phonegap based and don't work in this instance.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the right of the ripple emulator, open the "settings" tab, you'll see "cross domain proxy", set this to "disabled".